# how to realize an automatic bpeek?

Tags: bash, lsf

I am on a cluster equiped with IBM LSF job system.

I want to realize a feature, so that I can peek current output of every job I am running

So I write

```
for((i=2;i<=$(bjobs|grep RUN|wc -l)+1;i+=1)); do bpeek -f $(bjobs | awk '{print $1}'| head -n $i|tail -1);done
```

However, since `bpeek` enters into peeking mode, the loop is not gonna loop.

So I thought maybe I could kill `bpeek` at the end of each peak. However I found that PID of `bpeek` is not listed in `ps -ef`. So this seems not working.

Does anyone knows how to work around this?

Comment: bpeek will definitely be in ps.

Comment: @123 Hi. I tried it. At least `ps -ef|grep bpeek` only returns grep itself

Comment: bpeek will exec() a process called nios.  You can ps -ef | grep for that.

Comment: @MichaelClosson Hi, MichaelClosson. I am curious how do you know that?

Comment: You can use `strace`. You can also check the child processes of the shell that ran the bpeek.